# DataInputStream readLine() deprecated

Tags: java, io, deprecated, readline, datainputstream

I need to use the DataInputStream, since I need the deprecated readLine() functionality and I don't know the exact file format of the input file (i.e. what line ending is used), but also need to read binary encoded primitives.

This is similar to this question:

[Is there a class that exposes an unbuffered readLine method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331744/is-there-a-class-that-exposes-an-unbuffered-readline-method-in-java)

My suggestion is to use something like this

```
public class SaveDataInputStream extends DataInputStream {
  public SaveDataInputStream(InputStream in) {super(in);}
  public String readLineSave() throws IOException {
    // ???
  }
}
```

and to use the readLine() method content that can be found in the DataInputStream class (this is similar to the accepted answer in the referred question). However I don't fully understand why the method was deprecated and would prefer to know if it is relevant for my code.

The javadoc says: **This method does not properly convert bytes to characters.**

But what does that mean? Should I worry about that and what could happen in the worst case? Is it possible to write my own method that fixes the issue (efficiency is not really a concern)?

*Hint: new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(..)); is not the correct answer...*

Comment: It would be easier to know how to read the file if you showed the code used to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I found an example of the method working incorrectly as compared to BufferedReader.readLine(). Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "喜\n";
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes());
    DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(in);
    System.out.println(d.readLine()); // prints å

    in = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    System.out.println(br.readLine()); // prints 喜
  }
}
```

Basically, it doesn't appear that DataInputStream handles multi-byte characters at all since it basically does char next = (char)in.read(); for each character.

Essentially, I think that you need at least a very small buffer in order to properly read multi-byte characters. That said, you could probably build your custom method on top of InputStreamReader directly instead of BufferedReader, since that will properly handle multi-byte characters. Alternatively, if you know you're always going to be dealing with ascii then you're probably safe using the deprecated method.

EDIT: it's also worth noting that even DataInputStream buffers internally in order to properly handle \r\n line endings. In jdk7, at least, the handling for \r is:

```
          case '\r':
            int c2 = in.read();
            if ((c2 != '\n') && (c2 != -1)) {
                if (!(in instanceof PushbackInputStream)) {
                    in = new PushbackInputStream(in);
                }
                ((PushbackInputStream)in).unread(c2);
            }
            break loop;
```

Thus, if we encounter something like \ra, the a is unread back onto a pushback input stream, which maintains an internal buffer of unread bytes.

Comment: Accepted this answer, because it gives an example of the readLine() method failing. I'm not sure how I would go about fixing the conversion problem, but since my input is only ASCII, it's not really a concern for me.

Answer (score 4):

What they mean when they say `readLine()` was deprecated because it doesn't properly convert characters is that it does not allow you to specify the character encoding, for instance UTF-8 vs. CP1252.  This means that data written using one character encoding would most likely fail if read one a system that defaulted to a different character encoding.

So, do you need to worry about it?  Sure.  Methods are deprecated to provide a warning to developers that it can possibly go away in the future.  That said, according to the JavaDoc, `readLine()` was deprecated in JDK 1.1, which was a LOOONG time ago.

As to your point of not wanting a `BufferedReader` because of buffering, I'd say don't use it.  Use one of the other classes that extend [Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) or, if you want to be that extreme, roll your own.  There is nothing stopping you from creating your own class called DataInputReader, tacking on methods to read your primitives, and providing a proper `readLine()` implementation to suit your needs.

However, if you are reading binary encoded data, I would recommend NOT using a Reader at all, and sticking with a `InputStream` so you can read raw `byte`s and handle the conversions yourself.  `Reader`s were designed with the handling of character encoding in mind, and as such have a tendency to modify what you are reading under the premise that it is trying to convert binary data to character strings.